# Discord bot not updating with random numbers

Tags: python, random, discord.py, bots

I have been learning how to create a discord bot using [Repl.it](https://repl.it/%7E) and I have gotten to a stage where it is mostly functional. The purpose of the bot is generate random character for D&D 5e.However, I am having issues with generating random responses from the bot.

The only way I have managed to make a different output is to restart the bot. The code I am using is below, some things have been omitted for conciseness:

````
```python
import discord
import os
import random
from random import choice
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = discord.Client()

def file_to_list(filename):
    thefile = open(filename, "r")
    rows = [line for line in thefile]
    thefile.close()
    for i, r in enumerate(rows):
        rows[i] = r.replace("\n", "")
    return rows

a = file_to_list("Alignment.txt")
al = choice(a)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("#alignment"):
        await message.channel.send(al)
          
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```
````

Comment: You do the randomization only once when you start the program. You have to do it when the event is called.

Comment: Sorry, I have the feeling that I don't understand the meaning of your question. You know where you create the random values, after all it's your code. Moving those code lines from that place to the beginning of the function shouldn't be a problem. So I'm not sure what you mean with "how would i do that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the randomisation when the function is called:

```py
import random
def your_function:
     random.randint(your things)
```